# Lightning lead conversion page cancel button to redirect back to lead record

Tags: lightning, leads, lead-conversion, urlhacking, custom-url

We have created a custom button that will redirect to the lightning lead conversion page.

The URL we used is below:
/lightning/cmp/runtime_sales_lead__convertDesktopConsole?leadConvert__leadId={leadId}&retURL=%2F{leadId}

Right now, when the lead conversion page is opened, clicking the Cancel button does nothing.
Is there a way that by using only the URL we can make the Cancel button redirect back to the lead record?